# How to Restart Celery Wroker ran by Supervisord

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, supervisord

I am running celery on production using supervisord. My supervisor configuration is below.

```
[program:celeryd]
command=%(ENV_PROJECT_PATH)s/scripts/celery_worker.sh
stdout_logfile=%(ENV_PROJECT_PATH)s/celeryd.log
stderr_logfile=%(ENV_PROJECT_PATH)s/celeryd.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
stopwaitsecs=1000
priority=1000
```

My command to run celery worker is

```
celery_path=$(which celery)
$celery_path -A Project_Name worker --loglevel=info
```

I want to ask, how to restart celery worker when my codebase changes in production?

Comment: What's the problem with `supervisorctl restart celeryd`?

Comment: I used `supervisorctl restart celeryd` but after using this multiple times, server slows down. When I check ram, most of the ram was occupied by celery workers. There were almost 15 workers running in background.

Comment: I had the same problem. The paramater `killasgroup=true` in the supervisord script solved it for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue I run into is that long running tasks may get killed if you tell supervisor to killasgroup which would result in lost data.

The solution I've moved to using is to tell the mainprocess to TERM which will kill off the workers as they finish their tasks. supervisor will then restart the main process after all the workers finish.

```
ps aux | grep celery.*MainProcess | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -TERM
```

This is also related.
[Celery Production Graceful Restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42812125/celery-production-graceful-restart)

Answer (score 1):

Add following in supervisor file and restart supervisor.

> killasgroup=true